# No overload for matches delegate 'System.Action'

Tags: c#, action

```
public void UpdateDataGrid(bool newInsert = false)
    {

        //ThreadSafe (updating datagridview from AddEventForm is not allowed otherwise 
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new Action(UpdateDataGrid));
        }
        else
        {
            Util.PopulateDataGridView(ref this.EventsDataGridView,newInsert);
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to provide the optional parameter to new Action().

I tried new Action(UpdateDataGrid) but still throws a runtime error.

Thanks

Comment: why you are not using the generic one?

Comment: firstly , is it a cross thread exception?

Comment: No it doesn't throw cross thread exception. It complained about parameter mismatch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a method delegate encapsulating the invocation of your method, passing the argument originally specified, like so:

```
() => UpdateDataGrid(newInsert)
```

In context:

```
public void UpdateDataGrid(bool newInsert = false)
{

    //ThreadSafe (updating datagridview from AddEventForm is not allowed otherwise 
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() => UpdateDataGrid(newInsert)));
    }
    else
    {
        Util.PopulateDataGridView(ref this.EventsDataGridView,newInsert);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works. Can it be done without using lambdas ?
If there's no parameters Invoke(new Action(UpdateDataGrid) works, why doesn't this one work Invoke(new Action(UpdateDataGrid(newInsert))

Comment: @Marin you can replace any lambda expression with its corresponding delegate

Comment: It works without lambdas for parameterless methods because `UpdateDataGrid` represents the method *delegate* (i.e. a “pointer” to the method); notice the missing `()` at the end. `UpdateDataGrid(newInsert)`, on the other hand, represents an *invocation* of the method.

Comment: In other words: `UpdateDataGrid` is equivalent to `() => UpdateDataGrid()`, not `UpdateDataGrid()`.

Comment: thanks for the last comment. So in a way () => UpdateDataGrid() is a lambda whose end result is pretty much a delegate

Comment: Yes. `() => UpdateDataGrid()` is a lambda that serves as an anonymous function whose body consists of an expression corresponding to an invocation of the `UpdateDataGrid` method.